# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) when running Windows 10 VM

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install a Windows 10 VM on Oracle VM VirtualBox ver. 5.1.22 on Ubuntu 17.04, but whenever I try to run it, I get the following errors:

> The virtual machine 'Windows 10' has terminated unexpectedly during
> startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
>
> Result Code:
> NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component:
> MachineWrap
> Interface:
> IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}

And:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or
> there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall
> virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> where: suplibOsInit
>
> what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is
> not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I'm almost completely new to Linux and Ubuntu so please try to be simple.

Comment: It's actually quite simple: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings.

Comment: @John This isn't a forum. If you have a question please post an actual question.

Comment: @MichaelBay I understand but my comment was not a new question, it was a clarification of a sub-case of the original question. Still, I will remove it.

Comment: @John If you have a BIOS system then your problem *is* different, not a "sub-case".

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with the same issue all night I finally found a way to keep Secure Boot enabled & got Virtualbox VMs running properly- in Ubuntu Xenial (16.04.3).

I used [`ppa:costamagnagianfranco/virtualbox-ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecostamagnagianfranco/+archive/ubuntu/virtualbox-ppa). Though maybe another one would work - possibly even the official one - I didn't try.

A key part of the process was signing the kernel module, and [these instructions](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail) worked for me.

Comment: I use `efitools` and `sbsigntools` to create and enroll keys and sign modules. If you don't use windows, `efitools` can be used to take over your EFI keys.